# which cross platform mobile development tools is free license or free

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, development-environment

I want to create apps for Android and iPhone devices using HTML5,CSS and JavaScript.But i don't  know which cross platform mobile development tools is free license or free.I would like your advice on which free tools I can use.

Answer (score 1):

[Intel XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/tools) is based on HTML5 and is free and rich